# Changing UINavigationBar BackgroundImage causing the Views to move up

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i am working on an existing code, but changing the Background image of UINavigationBar is causing the Views below the navigationBar to move up throughout the application.

I am not doing anything in the code, just replacing the old background-image (plain Red) with new background-image (plain White with a thin Red line on the top).

I am keeping the name of both images same, and the dimensions of both old/new image is also same.

If change the old image again, the View comes back to its original position.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening, it seems really weird.

[image: Old Image:]

[image: New Image:]

Answer (score 0):

The alpha channel of the image wasn't set properly, so iOS was taking it as a transparent image.
Fixed the alpha channel and the problem is gone.